# How to do a package in git-bash (msys2) in windows?

Tags: windows, git-bash, fish, msys2

In linux when I use fish shell there is a feature called [abbreviation](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html) where I can make a list of abbreviation to use when I type in the terminal is autocompleted. For example:

Context: I have a list of abbreviation like:

```
gs = git status    
gl = git log
```

In the git-bash terminal for windows I would like to do:

1. type the text "gs"
2. I press the keyboard "space"
3. the terminal overwrite the text "gs" for the text "git status"

For now I didn't find a package for to do this, so I would like to try to do something myself, but I don't know what to learn for to do this.

In [zsh is possible to do something using scripts](https://dev.to/frost/fish-style-abbreviations-in-zsh-40aa). I read something how to install zsh in git-bash and [watch a video in youtube doing something](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SE1UtrtH9mo&t=479s&ab_channel=AutomationDojos), but I would like only adding the feature abbreviation.

What should I learn for to do or install in my git-bash?

Answer (score 0):

This should be somewhat easy to do using AutoHotKey.

It has a feature called "Hot Strings" which can be made context sensitive.

You could use a script similar to this example:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#variant

Something like this (not tested):

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class GitBash
::gs ::git status
::gl ::git log
```

Comment: This is a huge overkill. I believe Bash has command aliases built in.

Comment: That is interesting, but is over the context of git-bash, msys2 and scripts. And about alias I think that abbreviations are better than aliases because when a person sees someone using a alias isn't easy to understand the command behind the alias, but during the use of an abbreviation the people can see the real command.